# Firebase transactions, changing two or more child node values at the same time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

So I have a simple booking system where I allow users to reserve tickets using Firebase. I'm using transactions to avoid concurrency issues.

Basically this is the structure of the DB:

```
TerminalID:
    BussID:
       SeatID:
           TempEmail:
```

So this is an example where I want to book seats for bus number 1. seatList is the list of seats with seatIDs that the user wants to book. And for reserving the booking, I add a temporary email to the seatID.

```
DatabaseReference postRef = mDatabase.child("terminal").child("1");
postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        if(mutableData.getValue() == null){
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < seatList.size(); i++) {
            if (mutableData.child(Integer.toString(seatList.get(i))).child("tempEmail").getValue() == null) {
                mutableData.child(Integer.toString(seatList.get(i))).child("tempEmail").setValue(mUser.getEmail());
            }
            else{
                Transaction.abort();
            }
        }

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Transaction completed
        if (b == true){                                                         
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Someone just reserved them!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Rules:

```
"terminal": {
  ".read": true,
  //".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'",
  "$bid": {
    "$sid": {
      "uid": {
        ".write": "data.val() === 'null' || data.val() === auth.id"
      },
      "tempEmail": {
        ".write": "auth != null"
      },
      "booked": {
        ".write": false
      },
      "email": {
        ".write": false
      }
    }
  }
},
```

However, I get a permission denied error. I've double checked the rules, and I have allowed anyone to write just to make sure that it wasn't the rules. I suspect that this is because I'm trying to update more than 1 child node? However I've also attempted to book only 1 seat and this error still occurs. So I'm thinking it may be because I'm trying set the value of a child node, which is perhaps not allowed. Or there is perhaps something wrong with my code in general?

EDIT: I made a mistake, it does work when I set write = true to the top of the JsonObject.

Comment: Please include your rules and actual structure (not a representation) in your question (as text)

Comment: Did you added rules as {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: @AndréKool Sorry about that, its updated now!

Comment: @R.Anjali I've updated the post to include rules, I think it's similar to your proposal.

Comment: @AndréKool All good, thanks!

Comment: One mistake is that you need to put `return` before `Transaction.abort();`. I don't think it causes the error message, but it will cause other problems.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the simplest rules with which you tried this and still got a permission denied? Can you also show a snippet of the actual JSON you are updating (as text, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). And finally, can you replace all variables such as `Integer.toString(seatList.get(i))` in your code with hard-coded values? That will make it much more likely that we can spot what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The reason I put it there is because I want to ensure an atomic transaction, i.e. If I wanted to book 5 tickets and simultaneously someone else else books one of those spots before me, I want to cancel the entire transaction.